# `@{}` does not remove space at the edge of the table?

Tags: tables, spacing

For the following MWE,

```
\documentclass[oneside,11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\begin{table}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}cYYY@{}}
        \toprule
        Present State & Input & Next State & Output\\
        \midrule
        00            &  00   &  0         &  0 \\ 
        00            &  00   &  0         &  0 \\ 
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

the use of `@{}` does not seem to remove the spaces at the edge as seen in the picture. I basically want the first and the last rows to be more "symmetrically" spaced with respect to the edges. Is this possible ?

[image]

Comment: Actually it is, but the last column is centered and is of a certain width and `Output` is less than this width.

Comment: If you need to use `tabularx` you can adjust that space with: `{@{}cYYY@{\hskip-11mm}}`

Comment: @Ivan that is bad advise if the OP then later inserts a value wider than `Output` then it stickes out inthe the right margin.

Comment: why do you want to stretch the columns apart? it makes the table harder to read for no benefit at all.

Comment: actually the other tables that I am working on have 6-7 columns with lots of numbers packed in each and they, in my opinion, looked better with their columns spaced apart. To be consistent I wanted the above table to also be a little wide, but I suppose you are right.

Comment: they may look better if you just look at the page as a picture but it is harder for the reader to scan across and connect the data from one column to the next. (I wrote tabularx and I would never use it for such a table:-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The last column is as wide as the previous two, with “Output” centered in that width. There is actually *no* padding on the right.

In this case you don't want to use `tabularx`, but rather `tabular*`

[image]

```
\documentclass[oneside,11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}

\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}cccc@{}}
\toprule
Present State & Input & Next State & Output\\
\midrule
00            &  00   &  0         &  0 \\ 
00            &  00   &  0         &  0 \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}

\caption{Some caption}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

However, I'd restrain from widening the table unless it's almost as wide as the text width: large white spaces make the table harder to read.

Answer (score -1):

[image]

```
\documentclass[oneside,11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}
%\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\begin{table}
    \begin{tabular}{@{}cccc@{}}
        \toprule
        Present State & Input & Next State & Output\\
        \midrule
        00            &  00   &  0         &  0 \\ 
        00            &  00   &  0         &  0 \\ 
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

EDIT

```
\documentclass[oneside,11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}
%\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\begin{table}
    \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} cccc}
        \toprule
        Present State & Input & Next State & Output\\
        \midrule
        00            &  00   &  0         &  0 \\ 
        00            &  00   &  0         &  0 \\ 
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular*}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes but I would like to fit the table to the text width.

Comment: That is not really an answer of the OPs question

Comment: You forgot the `@{}` at the end. But egreg already answered this....